# Send Data from one Activity to another - not Working

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-checkbox

I have a TO DO List, and when I check the checkbox in one Activity I want the CheckBox and the text that is next to the Checkbox to go to another Activity. this is my Adapter:

```
public class MyItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>  {

private final Context context;
private final String[] values;

    public MyItemAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.item_list, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
}

@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, parent, false);
    CheckBox textView = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    textView.setText(values[position]);

    return rowView;
  }

public static SparseBooleanArray getCheckedItemPositions() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public static void remove(Object pos) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void changeData(String[] items) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public static void setAdapter(MyItemAdapter mAdapter) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

This is my First Activity code:

```
         final CheckBox check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
             check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FinishedItems.class);
            intent.putExtra("check", items);
            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
            extras.putString("status", "Data Recived");
            intent.putExtras(extras);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
    }
```

This is my Second Activity code:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String check = intent.getStringExtra("check");
    ((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1)).setText(check);
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String status = bundle.getString("status");
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
```

And Finaly this is my Log cat:

```
 02-18 10:33:24.779: D/AndroidRuntime(1575): Shutting down VM
 02-18 10:33:24.779: W/dalvikvm(1575): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception       (group=0x40015560)
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{com.Stanton.quicktodolist/com.Stanton.quicktodolist.MainActivity}:    java.lang.NullPointerException
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at com.Stanton.quicktodolist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
 02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    ... 11 more
```

Please Help me

Comment: What is in you 'items' variable?

Comment: problem is in MainActivity class so add relevant part of code with question

Comment: Also why would you `putExtra` on the intent and then create a bundle with extras to add to the intent?

Answer (score 0):

This line of your stacktrace

```
02-18 10:33:24.789: E/AndroidRuntime(1575):    at com.Stanton.quicktodolist.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
```

points you to the error. Line 70 in the MainActivity causes a null pointer. It is often helpful to study and understand stacktraces. If you cannot figure it out yourself, show us the onCreate method of the MainActivity.

Comment: In that it points out the error to the OP and gives him the opportunity to figure out this kind of problem on his own the next time. I assume, that if he looks at line 70 of his code, the problem will be clear, this is usually true with NPE.

Comment: An answer is a POSSIBLE SOLUTION, yours is just a suggestion.

Comment: No, that is not true, read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for details. Quote: "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful" and later "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."

Comment: This type of extremely basic and unchanging (if still very important) advice is generally better as a comment however.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you replace the intent extra by the bundle extra just try this code and let me know pelase

```
final CheckBox check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
             check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FinishedItems.class);
            intent.putExtra("check", items);
            //Bundle extras = new Bundle();
           // extras.putString("status", "Data Recived");
            intent.putExtras("status", "Data Recived");
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

    }
```

And the int the second activity

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
    String check = intent.getStringExtra("check");
    ((CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1)).setText(check);
   // Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    String status = intent.getStringExtra("status");
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
```